# ansible delegate_to run for multiple times

Tags: ansible, local

I am trying to run certain tasks using `delegate_to localhost` or `connection: local` and other tasks on the remote host. however the task is executed on the localhost multiple times when i use "delegate_to: localhost"

my inventory

```
localhost ansible_host=127.0.0.1 ansible_connection=local ansible_python_interpreter="{{ansible_playbook_python}}"

[master1]
ip-10-90-148-195.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal
[master2]
ip-10-90-149-130.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal
[master3]
ip-10-90-150-239.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal

[master:children]
master1
master2
master3

[worker]
ip-10-90-148-206.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal
ip-10-90-149-178.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal
ip-10-90-150-86.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal

[all:vars]
ansible_user="core"
ansible_ssh_private_key_file="~/.ssh/id_rsa"
```

my task:

```
- name: host name
  shell: echo `hostname` >> /tmp/123
  #delegate_to: localhost
  #connection: local
```

if i comment `delegate_to: localhost` and `connection: local`, i will get a file /tmp/123 on each remote host with their own hostname inside it. expected result.

however if i uncomment either one of them,the task will be executed 6 times on the localhost. meaning /tmp/ls on localhost will have localhost's hostname printed 6 times in it.

my goal is simple, i just want to run certain task on all host as per define in playbook `hosts: groupa:groupb`, and certain task on localhost, but 1 time only. i thought this is straight forward but i have been spending hours but no result.

Comment: try `run_once: True`

Answer (score 6):

if your `hosts` contains `groupa:groupb` then yes make sense to have 6 entries (it runs the tasks 6 times on localhost)
you need to add the option `run_once: true` in your task level.
or modify the playbook to run on the localhost only.

Comment: thank you, however i have another issue. using `connection: local`, the playbook run expected in ansible core, but not in ansible tower. the task carried out succesfully with `changed: true`, but nothing get change